# Login Form in Node.js & MongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm almost beginner to web dev. I'm making a pretty basic web page for login authentication. All I'm trying to do is to check user credentials (username & password) on my LoginPage from the database (mongoose) and redirect to the next page (MainPage) if they are correct.

Login.ejs (.html) file

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>    
    <body>    
        <form id="form_Login" action="/MainPage" method="post">
            <input id="txt_username" type="text" required>
            <br><input id="txt_password" type="password" required>              
            <br><input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
var User = new Schema ({
    username : String,
    password : String
});

mongoose.model('User',User);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDB');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.render('LoginPage');
});

app.get('/MainPage',function(req, res) {
    res.render('MainPage');
});

app.post('/MainPage', function(req, res) {
    // new code should come over here
    res.redirect('/MainPage');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Bad Route!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's helpful to show any errors you are getting or to describe what undesired behavior your code demonstrates so that others can try to assist with specific questions rather than just a general task.

Comment: sir I've mentioned a comment in the second file where logic for code authentication from the db is required.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) library for that.
Not only does it provide you with a good way to create local authentication, you can later on integrate google, facebook and twitter (or any oAuth) social authentication methods.

You can read the documentation which should provide you with a good starting point, or any one of these examples:

- http://passportjs.org/docs
- http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/11/user-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/#.VYAS0PlViko
- http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.VYAS0vlViko
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local ( I have used this one in the past)

I suggest you start by using the passport-local scheme, which will give you exactly what you need. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm looking to try it in a simple way first, then move on ahead.

Comment: @user_47 it's very simple to setup, and it's much more safe, otherwise you will have to save passwords in none encrypted (which is not safe at all) plus you will have to create database models to save and load users, which re-invent the wheel? Just doing a text compare is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful links, Dory. The main issue here is with the MongoDB queries. I'm interested in a single line of code that will actually compare the value of my textbox with the values in the databases. I would go on and implement the Passport.js later.

Answer (score 1):

Use the body-parser middleware to get your form data and use it to query your database. First you need to do a `npm install body-parser`. Then you could try something like the following. Note that this is very rough code however and you should probably use some other excellent libraries to handle authentication.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema ({
    username : String,
    password : String
});

mongoose.model('User',User);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDB');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
    res.render('LoginPage');
});

app.get('/MainPage',function(req,res)
{
    res.render('MainPage');
});

app.post('/MainPage', function(req, res)
{
    // new code should come over here
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else if(user){
            res.redirect('/MainPage');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Invalid');
        }
    });

});

app.get('*', function(req,res)
{
    res.send('Bad Route!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Comment: Keep on getting this error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: I've slightly modified the answer. See if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bodyPasser to get input from the html. (**npm i body-parser**. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

You can use the mongoose to save the user and find the user (**npm i mongoose**) https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose.

I used here ejs.

Using the findOne you can find the register user is available or not https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne.

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require('express');
const bodyPasser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyPasser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB',{useNewUrlParser:true})
  .then(() => console.log('Connected!'));

  const userSchema = {
    email:String,
    password:String
  }

  const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("home")
})

app.get("/register",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("register")
})

app.get("/login",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("login")
})

app.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    newUser.save((err)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        res.render("secrets")
      }
    })
})

app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
   const username = req.body.username;
   const password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({email:username},(err,user)=>{
       if(err){
        console.log(err);
       }else{
        if(user){
            if(user.password === password){
                res.render("secrets")
            }
        }
        
       }
    })
})



app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("port is statrt at 3000");
})
```